# My XSD type is being ignored by MS' XSD.exe tool

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd.exe

My XSD has this in it, for a field which contains a date but may be empty:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="DateOrEmpty">
    <xs:union>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
          <xs:length value="0"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base='xs:dateTime' />
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
  </xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="NAME" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="BIRTHDAY" type="xs:dateTime" />
      <xs:element name="ANNIVERSARY" type="DateOrEmpty" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I run this through "XSD.exe myFile.xsd /classes" and get a resulting class like the following:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class person {

    private string nAMEField;
    private System.DateTime bIRTHDAYField;
    private string aNNIVERSARYField; //huh?
```

So what happened to my `DateOrEmpty` type? it's nowhere to be seen!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related but I am trying to use the custom tool MSDatasetGenerator and the error I get is: "Custom tool error: Failed to generate code. DataSet doesn't support 'union' or 'list' as simpleType."

Comment: Also, when I run xsd.exe at the command line I get the same thing. No issue yet when using the /classes switch.